# Cannot work with Stem and Tor

Tags: python, proxy, tor

I want to work with Tor through Stem module.The following is my code to get connected with Tor:

```
import sys
from stem.connection import connect

if __name__ == '__main__':
    controller = connect()

    if not controller:
        sys.exit(1)  # unable to get a connection

    print 'Tor is running version %s' % controller.get_version()
    controller.close()
```

However, i get following error when running the code:**Unable to connect to tor. Are you sure it's running?**

I turned on Tor and tested the code again and nothing happened. The problem is this line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    controller = connect()
```

Even if I enter the connect() method to Python interpreter I get the error. What is the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried the tutorial? https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html

Comment: @Wolph: Yes i have tried that and i faced another error:

raise stem.SocketError(exc)
stem.SocketError: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

By the way, i couldn't use the hashed password because it seems that the tutorial is using Linux Terminal to set hashed password for Tor and i don't have Terminal on my win7.

Comment: Ah... Windows, that could be tricky. Anyhow, it's basically telling you that it's not running properly (or not running at all). So either you have the wrong port or it just didn't start correctly.

Comment: You have added a line `ControlPort 9051` to your torrc file correct?  By default the controller doesn't listen on a port so you have to add that to your config to enable control connections.